# Log Level per appender for a single Logger

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Is it possible to configure different log levels for a single Logger based on the appender?

I realize this is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839647/how-to-configure-log4j-to-log-different-log-levels-to-different-files-for-the-sam), and this is as far as I had already got myself, but the problem with this is that the threshold applies to all loggers that log to that appender, whereas I only want the threshold to apply to a single logger.

i.e. So far I have something like this:

```
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Threshold=WARN
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.SimpleLayout

log4j.logger.mylogger=DEBUG,logfile
log4j.appender.logfile=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.logfile.DatePattern=${roll.pattern.daily}
log4j.appender.logfile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.logfile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{${datestamp}} [%t] %-5p %C{2} - %m%n
log4j.appender.logfile.File=mylogfile.log
```

I want **mylogger** DEBUG messages to be send to the **logfile** appender, but I also want **mylogger** INFO messages to be sent to the **stdout** appender (but for all other loggers only WARN ings). Using the Threshold to limit stdout to WARN restricts the output of **mylogger**.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Aha, I fixed it by changing

```
log4j.appender.stdout.Threshold=WARN
```

to

```
log4j.appender.stdout.Threshold=INFO
```

Should have been more careful first time round.

Comment: I recommend using the XML format, it's considerably easier to understand, IMO

Comment: agreed, and it exposes functionality that is not available through properties files.

Comment: Nice! This was very useful to me one year later :-D I did it on run time though, from within the application, like this: myAppender.setThreshold( Level.INFO ).

Comment: What about log4j2?