# Log4j - filtering out logs for current project only

Tags: java, log4j, filtering

Have `log4j.properties` file, that logs more than I expect,in particular, it logs events for Spring libraries.
 And it's needed only project specific events to be filtered.

Is it some filtering param,that specify what classes(project or namespace) should be logged?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes,  create a logger entry that uses the name of your package.

```
log4j.logger.com.my.package=INFO
```

Set your appender to a more verbose setting and set the root appender to a higher level like ERROR or WARN.

```
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, stdout
```

See this post: [Log4j | Updating the Log Level for the Appender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148141/log4j-updating-the-log-level-for-the-appender)

Comment: Can we do this in a Java? How do we set the logging to a specific package?

Answer (score 2):

From the [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) manual:

```
# Print only messages of level WARN or above in the package com.foo.
log4j.logger.com.foo=WARN
```

Replace `com.foo` with the one that want to be ignored and set the logging level to some high value like `WARN` or `ERROR`.

Answer (score 0):

I found another way of doing this.

I was having issues that when I was using level **DEBUG** or higher, the libs I used in my project were making it to the console.
It's better to properly configure your project, but you can get by just disabling the logger for a specific package.

In the snippet below, all packages that start with **org.*** were disabled.
Did the job for me.
Found this at the manual: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout

# Disables logger for all org.* packages
log4j.logger.org=OFF
```