# Undefined trace method for Log4J

Tags: java, maven, log4j

I am getting a weird compilation error in my Maven (version 3.1.0) project. I have added the following dependency to my POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

When I use the following code, I get a `The method trace(String) is undefined for type Logger` error.

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
...
private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Main.class);
...
logger.trace("message to be traced");
```

If i use e.g. debug instead of trace, though, the code compiles just fine.

What's might be wrong?

In case I have omitted some important information, please feel free to ask for it in comments. I will add them right away.

---

When I run the suggested `mvn dependency:tree` command, I get the following output.

```
biz.jezek:inscsdbdt:jar:1.0
+- com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-rt:jar:2.1.3:compile
|  +- javax.xml.ws:jaxws-api:jar:2.1:compile
|  |  \- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.1:compile
|  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.1.6:compile
|  +- com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj:saaj-impl:jar:1.3:compile
|  |  \- javax.xml.soap:saaj-api:jar:1.3:compile
|  +- com.sun.xml.stream.buffer:streambuffer:jar:0.7:compile
|  |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
|  +- com.sun.xml.stream:sjsxp:jar:1.0:compile
|  |  \- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0:compile
|  +- org.jvnet.staxex:stax-ex:jar:1.2:compile
|  +- com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal:resolver:jar:20050927:compile
|  \- org.jvnet:mimepull:jar:1.1:compile
+- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
+- biz.jezek:jdt:jar:1.0:compile
+- biz.jezek:utils:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
|  +- biz.jezek:dmsclient:jar:10.0.1:compile
|  \- biz.jezek:umsjavaclient:jar:10.0.1:compile
+- com.microsoft:sqljdbc:jar:4:compile
+- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
+- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.6.7:compile
+- junit:junit:jar:4.8.2:test (scope not updated to compile)
\- org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.8.4:test
```

Comment: What about the imports?

Comment: I have updated the code snippet. I do only import the Logger class, but that seems ok to me.

Comment: Could you please run `mvn dependency:tree -DoutputFile=DT.log` and post `DT.log` content ?

Answer (score -1):

Check isTraceEnabled() on your logger.  This may allow you to see if you have enabled

```
log4j.rootLogger=TRACE
```

See [Log4j | Updating the Log Level for the Appender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148141/log4j-updating-the-log-level-for-the-appender) as well

Comment: the method "trace" is missing