# Log4j.xml category multiple appender-ref with different priorities

Tags: java, log4j

I want to be able to have different appenders with different priority levels

e.x.

```
<category name="my.package" additivity="false">  
    <priority value="fatal" />  
    <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="fileAppender" />
</category>
```

I thought something like this would work, but it doesn't

```
<category name="my.package" additivity="false">  
    <priority value="fatal" ref="consoleAppender" /> 
    <priority value="info" ref="fileAppender"/> 
    <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="fileAppender" />
</category>
```

Comment: I think this is duplicate question to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154539/log4j-log-level-per-appender-for-a-single-logger

Comment: @MilanBaran almost but I want it for only the my.package so need to use category tag. unless anyone else knows a better way in xml file

Comment: @MWright I'm having the very same problem at the moment and after trying some things it starts to look like logging a particular package/class to different appenders with different log levels is something that can't be done... I'd appreciate if somebody could confirm this (did you find any solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

I have had some personal success with this by creating a separate category for each appender.

Something like:

```
<category name="my.package">  
<priority value="INFO"/> 
<appender-ref ref="Appender1" />
</category>  

<category name="my.package">  
<priority value="WARN"/> 
<appender-ref ref="Appender2" />
</category>
```

Comment: This doesnt work, if you write multiple categories with the same name they will be overwritten.