# log4j, need to display only INFO and ERROR message in log file

Tags: java, log4j

I am new to log4j and worked to setup on eclipse and its running. I understood the chain of priority in the levels and this is my properties file config:

```
log4j.rootLogger=ALL, file, console

log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
logrj.appender.console.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p %c{1} - %m%n

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=logs/justfortesting.log
log4j.appender.file.Append=true
log4j.appender.file.ImmediateFlush=true
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1KB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=2
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %d{Z} [%t] %-5p (%F:%L) - %m%n
```

My question is

Is it possible to print only INFO and ERROR type of messages in log files with properties file configuration

Comment: Are you trying to prevent logging via `DEBUG`, for example?

Comment: Sorry i didn't get you clearly, what I exactly need is Include/Print only INFO and ERROR logger messages in log file. Rest of logger(DEBUG, WARN, FATAL) message need to exclude from printing in log file.

Comment: are you sure you want to exclude your own warnings? If you want to exclude some components warnings, you can configure the logging per component

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally I got the solution for my requirement. Here I used concept of filters         i.e LevelRangeFilter. And for every logging level we defined appender.

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, file, console, file1

log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
logrj.appender.console.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p %c{1} - %m%n

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=logs/justfortesting.log
log4j.appender.file.Append=true
log4j.appender.file.ImmediateFlush=true
log4j.appender.file.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.file.filter.a=org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter
log4j.appender.file.filter.a.LevelMin=INFO
log4j.appender.file.filter.a.LevelMax=INFO
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1KB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=2
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %d{Z} [%t] %-5p (%F:%L) - %m%n

log4j.appender.file1=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file1.File=logs/justfortesting.log
log4j.appender.file1.Append=true
log4j.appender.file1.ImmediateFlush=true
log4j.appender.file1.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.file1.filter.g=org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter
log4j.appender.file1.filter.g.LevelMin=ERROR
log4j.appender.file1.filter.g.LevelMax=ERROR
log4j.appender.file1.MaxFileSize=1KB
log4j.appender.file1.MaxBackupIndex=2
log4j.appender.file1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %d{Z} [%t] %-5p (%F:%L) - %m%n

log4j.logger.com.log4j=DEBUG, file, console, file1

log4j.additivity.com.log4j=false
```

If any one suggest to reduce the above properties configuration for same requirement,, please comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
log4j.appender.file.Threshold=INFO
```

Also see [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154539/log-level-per-appender-for-a-single-logger) and [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customloglevels.html#DefiningLevelsInConfiguration)