# Specify multiple loggers with multiple handlers for one class in java.util.logging

Tags: java, logging, java.util.logging

Is it possible to define two separate loggers each with its dedicated file handler for one class using java.util.logging? I want separate log file for errors and other application messages. I am trying but no success so far.

Can anyone suggest what is the possible solution for this? I am initializing one logger at the start of application which reads configurations from logging.properties and creating other logger within one function of the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know log4j can allow you to send messages with different thresholds (errors or application messages) to seperate files.  Perhaps you could look into that.

Take a look at [How to configure log4j to log different log levels to different files for the same logger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839647/how-to-configure-log4j-to-log-different-log-levels-to-different-files-for-the-sam)