# In log4j2 Can I Have Multiple Loggers with the Same Name?

Tags: java, xml, logging, log4j2

In log4j2 is it legal to have multiple loggers with the same name? If it isn't, how would I be able to accomplish the same thing?

```
<logger name="com.foo.bar" level="error" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="SMTPAppender" /> 
    <appender-ref ref="stdout" />
</logger>
<logger name="com.foo.bar" level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFile"/>
</logger>
<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="stdout"/>
</root>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question has already been resolved here:
[How to configure log4j to log different log levels to different files for the same logger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839647/how-to-configure-log4j-to-log-different-log-levels-to-different-files-for-the-sa)

You must use an appender, as you cannot have two loggers with the same name.

Hope this helps!