# How to make log4j2 create different logging files with Spring Boot and Maven

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, logging, log4j2

I am a beginner and have a problem with setting log4j2 in my Spring Boot application. I've tried to do it myself for about a week now, read many hints, posts and tutorials and still didn't find solution. Could anyone pls help me with that? I would like to create different files for different log levels like error.log, warn.log and so on.

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.assessment.ww</groupId>
    <artifactId>Assessment_Exercise</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Assessment_Exercise</name>
    <description>Spring Boot Project</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>

        <File name="File" target="logs/app.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </File>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
<!--        Log everything -->
        <Logger name="com.assessment.ww.Assessment_Exercise" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
        </Logger>

<!--        Log everything in Spring Boot -->
        <Logger name="org.springframework.boot" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
        </Logger>

<!--        Log everything in Spring Core -->
        <Logger name="org.springframework.core" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
        </Logger>

        <Root level="all">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

starting class

```
package com.assessment.ww.Assessment_Exercise;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class AssessmentExerciseApplication {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(AssessmentExerciseApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(AssessmentExerciseApplication.class, args);

        logger.info("Starting SB app");
    }
}
```

I also have such a warning - maybe it will help: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjy2f.png)

It prints my logger.info message (but why without formatting?) but do not create any files.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJtK4.png)

Thank You in advance for any advices.

Comment: Check this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839647/how-to-configure-log4j-to-log-different-log-levels-to-different-files-for-the-sa

Comment: Thank You for comment but it still doesn't work. Whatever I do it does not create a file. It also does not change the pattern of log in console what is pretty wierd because I have set a pattern in Console in log4j2.xml (looks like it does not read log4j2.xml file). It prints my logger messages in the console though.

Comment: I pasted standard log4j2.xml data from apache log4j configuration site into different project (also simple Spring Boot + Maven - pretty similar to this one) and it works fine in the console output (logs in the console are shown with a pattern that I define in the log4j2.xml Console section). Is it possible that my problem has something to do with Maven?

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I've found a solution. The problem was Logback - even that I disabled it in spring-boot-starter-web dependency in pom.xml, it was still active in spring-boot-starter-data-jpa and spring-boot-starter-actuator.
So now my pom.xml looks like this:

```
...
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
...
```