# How to log more info on no 200 HTTP responses?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I need to log more info (**method**, **path** and **response**) when any of my controller returns **non 200 HTTP** responses but in *another separately* log. Basically, when a controller returns a 404 (for example), I want it to print just after the controller logs my log like this:

```
method: GET, path: localhost/product/123, response: 404 NOT_FOUND
```

I have tried to override `logback-spring.xml` but didn't get anywhere, tried to create my own `EvaluatorFilter` still no hope, succeeded with `MDC` but it will print in every log so this option doesn't help me.

Question: can I do this just by creating a `logback-spring.xml` file to change the **ERROR** log type? If yes, can someone give me an example, if not, can it be done in another way?
Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use log4j and specify seperate log files based on the log level as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1839673/17173476), in your case have a seperate file for errors and log your shorter version with warn.